# Update : collecting Arabic tweets and save it in csv using python

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I'm having a problem collecting Arabic tweets and save them in a CSV file

when I open the CSV file the tweets is like this

[image]

here is the code

```
import tweepy
import csv


# Twitter API credentials

consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = ".."
access_key = "..."
access_secret = "...."

auth= tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key,access_secret)
api= tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)


csvFile=open('tweets.csv','a',newline='')
csvWriter=csv.writer(csvFile)
#truncated=False,
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="اكتئاب",since="2021-01-30",truncated=False,tweet_mode="extended", count=1).items():

    if (not tweet.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in tweet.full_text):
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8-sig')])
```

**please I need your help :'(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the empty lines you get, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191811/1431750):

   - add the parameter `newline=''` to the `open(...)` statement
2. To get the full tweet text (280 chars), use [Extended Mode](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#standard-api-methods) when invoking the API and/or the `Cursor()`

   - `tweet_mode='extended'`
   - and use the parameter `full_text` instead of just `text` to get the text of each tweet.
   - You'll also need to [handle retweets](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#handling-retweets) slightly differently.
3. For the Full URLs, see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298771/1431750):

   ```py
   for url in status.entities['urls']:
       links = url['expanded_url']
   ```

Comment: I've tried the tweet_mode and full_text but still not getting the complete tweet, see the code I've edited .

Comment: Give an example of a tweet where the `full_text` is not the _full_ `full_text`. (Actual tweet text visible on twitter vs `full_text`.)

Comment: thank you I check again and its work .. but I have a problem with the CSV file please check my update .. :(

Comment: Put the `encoding='utf-8-sig'` part in `open`, not on `full_text`. _Edit:_ I see you've answered that part yourself below.

Comment: Also, use [`open` as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files): `with open('tweets.csv','a',newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvFile:`. The for loops, if blocks, etc. should all be indented in a level under that.

Comment: Another thing - don't modify your existing question to ask a new question once you already have an answer which solved the original question. Generally, ask a new question with the specifics of just the new/next problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer that if I add these two lines to my code it will fix it

```
#coding:utf8
csvFile=open('tweets.csv','a',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

[the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905380/unable-to-save-arabic-decoded-unicode-to-csv-file-using-python)